# How to keep a chrome extension service worker active or restore it from popup

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've been developing a chrome extension for a few months.
The extension works fine as most cases, but there is an issue that I could not solve and kept bothering me

I've even posted here before: [chrome exension background script keeps removing listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77374298/chrome-exension-background-script-keeps-removing-listener)

After a lot of searching and reading I found this:
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/service_workers/service-worker-lifecycle/

> **Idle and shutdown**: Normally, Chrome terminates a service worker when
> one of the following conditions is met:
>
> After 30 seconds of inactivity. Receiving an event or calling an
> extension API resets this timer.

If I understood correctly, after 30 seconds without handling events, even if the service worker has active listeners, it will be shut down to preserve resources.

This explain all the random issues I was facing and it makes sense from the perspective of saving resources.

The question is, how to RE-ACTIVE service worker from the pop up script?
All I've see people mention is to call `chrome.runtime.reload();` which will reload the entire extension and cause a glitch.

This whole "saving resources" design has a major flaw since it removes active listeners to events.
Follow me:

1. install extension, service worker runs attach listeners and does whatever it want to do
2. user interacts with extension for some time
3. user stays idle for whatever reason
4. chrome terminates the service worker even thought there are listeners attached
5. user interacts with popup or with content script causing this to send a `sendMessage` to service worker [which no longer exists] then an exception is raised

What I am missing????
Unless there is a way to revive service worker from popup/content script this non-reponsive behavior will always occur

Comment: Assuming your code doesn't have any mistakes, it is a bug in Chrome as I already mentioned in your previous question. The reason you cited does not cause the problem as normally the worker automatically wakes up on an event. You can try to [keep the worker running indefinitely](/a/66618269) or just don't use a worker at all, which may be possible depending on what exactly the extension does.